# delayed logo fading into website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just wondering whats the best way to go about having the logo in top left corner to fade in after about 5 seconds after user has been on page?

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/elroyz/sjD8X/ with the logo in the corner

```
body {
background-color:#000;}
```

i only put this in because it wouldnt let me post without code

i read something about jquery delay but i know next to nothing about it so thought there might be another option

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't look like you've actually tried anything. SO is more "what am I doing wrong" over "what do I use".

Comment: If there's a jQuery method you "know next to nothing about", there's [an easy fix for that](http://api.jquery.com/)...

Comment: yeah i havent tried anything, i just wanted to put the image up there thought it was easier to explain.

Comment: @elroyz as another commenter has posted SO questions are usually about bits of code that you are working on i.e. "I've tried this but it doesn't work please help me" and not "tell me what to do". The answer below will give you the desired effect.

Comment: a bit of research would have shown you countless examples out there

Comment: i probably should have worded what i was saying a little better, im quite happy to try and figure this out myself just needed a push in the right direction which is the best way to go about it, not once did i say can someone do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('img').delay(5000).fadeOut(250);
```

This will fade out the img after 5 seconds. The time in the code is in ms.

Fore more info on this see

- [api.jquery.com/delay/](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)
- [api.jquery.com/fadeout/](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)
- [api.jquery.com/fadein/](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)

Comment: An important note from the [/delay/](http://api.jquery.com/delay) page you've linked to: "`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases."

Answer (score 2):

try to use this transitions.

http://www.problogdesign.com/coding/get-started-with-css3-transitions-today/

goodluck!

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="image path" />
```

CSS

```
img {opacity:0;-moz-transition: opacity 2s;-webkit-transition: opacity 2s;-o-transition: opacity 2s;transition: opacity 2s;}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3 animation. (With vendor prefixes because it is still new and experimental):

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadein {
  0%   { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

#logo {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation:    fadein 5s infinite;
  -o-animation:      fadein 5s infinite;
  animation:         fadein 5s infinite;
}
```